# How correct to make (move) the class internal in Java?

Tags: java

Structure of my project is:

```
/src/
----/action/
--------/impl/
------------ActionCalculateQuadrangle.interface
--------CalculateQuadrangle.class
--------Line.class
----/other packages/
```

Code `ActionCalculateQuadrangle.interface`:

```java
public interface ActionCalculateQuadrangle {
    double getArea(Quadrangle quadrangle);
    double getPerimeter(Quadrangle quadrangle);
    double getLengthLine(Line line);
    double getSlope(Line line);

    List<Point[]> getCombinationsElementsOver(Point[] points, int pointsOnOneLine);
    Point getCrossPoint(Line line1, Line line2);

    boolean isQuadrangle(Quadrangle quadrangle);
    boolean isPointsOnStraightLine(Point[] points);
    boolean isConvex(Quadrangle quadrangle);
    boolean isSquare(Quadrangle quadrangle);
    boolean isRhombus(Quadrangle quadrangle);
    boolean isTrapezoid(Quadrangle quadrangle);
    boolean isDeltoid(Quadrangle quadrangle);
    boolean isStraightPerpendicular(Line line1, Line line2);
    boolean isEqualLengthsDiagonals(Line line1, Line line2);
    boolean isCrossLines(Line line1, Line line2);
    boolean areSidesParallel(Line side1, Line side2);
}
```

Code `Line.class`:

```java
public class Line {
    private final Point p1;
    private final Point p2;

    public Line(Point p1, Point p2) {
        this.p1 = p1;
        this.p2 = p2;
    }

    public Point getP1() {
        return this.p1;
    }

    public Point getP2() {
        return this.p2;
    }
}
```

Part of code unity-class 'CalculateQuadrangle.class` (I cite part of the code so as not to clutter up the place):

```java
// ... some code

@Override
    public double getPerimeter(final Quadrangle quadrangle) {
        Line side1 = new Line(quadrangle.getP1(), quadrangle.getP2());
        Line side2 = new Line(quadrangle.getP2(), quadrangle.getP3());
        Line side3 = new Line(quadrangle.getP3(), quadrangle.getP4());
        Line side4 = new Line(quadrangle.getP1(), quadrangle.getP1());

        return getLengthLine(side1) + getLengthLine(side2) + getLengthLine(side3) + getLengthLine(side4);
    }

    @Override
    public double getLengthLine(final Line line) {
        Point p1 = line.getP1();
        Point p2 = line.getP2();

        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p2.getX() - p1.getX(), 2) + Math.pow(p2.getY() - p1.getY(), 2));
    }

    @Override
    public double getSlope(final Line line) {
        Point p1 = line.getP1();
        Point p2 = line.getP2();

        if ((p1.getY() == p2.getY()) || (p1.getX() == p2.getX())) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return (p2.getY() - p1.getY()) / (p2.getX() - p1.getX());
        }
    }

// ... some code
```

That's ok. But A want to make class 'Line' internal.

How I do it? Like this:

```java
// ... some code

// PUT IT HERE!
public class Line {
    private final Point p1;
    private final Point p2;

    public Line(Point p1, Point p2) {
        this.p1 = p1;
        this.p2 = p2;
    }

    public Point getP1() {
        return this.p1;
    }

    public Point getP2() {
        return this.p2;
    }
}

@Override
    public double getPerimeter(final Quadrangle quadrangle) {
        Line side1 = new Line(quadrangle.getP1(), quadrangle.getP2());
        Line side2 = new Line(quadrangle.getP2(), quadrangle.getP3());
        Line side3 = new Line(quadrangle.getP3(), quadrangle.getP4());
        Line side4 = new Line(quadrangle.getP1(), quadrangle.getP1());

        return getLengthLine(side1) + getLengthLine(side2) + getLengthLine(side3) + getLengthLine(side4);
    }

    @Override
    public double getLengthLine(final Line line) {
        Point p1 = line.getP1();
        Point p2 = line.getP2();

        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p2.getX() - p1.getX(), 2) + Math.pow(p2.getY() - p1.getY(), 2));
    }

    @Override
    public double getSlope(final Line line) {
        Point p1 = line.getP1();
        Point p2 = line.getP2();

        if ((p1.getY() == p2.getY()) || (p1.getX() == p2.getX())) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return (p2.getY() - p1.getY()) / (p2.getX() - p1.getX());
        }
    }

// ... some code
```

But compiler java show me error like this - `Class 'CalculateQuadrangle' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'getLengthLine(Line)' in 'ActionCalculateQuadrangle'`.

1. Declarate abstract - can't for me.
2. implement abstract method 'getLengthLine(Line)' in 'ActionCalculateQuadrangle'. That mean, what i must implement ALL abstract method, which have in the argument object class Line.

[image]

**How correct to make (move) the class internal?**

After update still have error:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Don't make a `public class` if you just want an inner class https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: @OneCricketeer, ok, now I'm maked just 'class Line' inside `class ClaculateQuadrangle` and still make error. **UPDATE** Was added screenshot in topic.

Comment: Looks fine to me, but the error is unrelated to the inner class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are seeing is because you now have two Line classes, and the method definition and interface definition are not referring to now the same class of `CalculateQuadrangle.Line`

Comment: Ok, outside class 'Line` was deleted, but still error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRLwr.png

Comment: In `interface ActionCalculateQuadrangle` I'm must use parameter `Line line` in method like this `double getLengthLine(CalculateQuadrangle.Line line);` or like this `double getLengthLine(Line line);` ?

Comment: Look at the output in the bottom window. `javax.sound.sampled.Line` is what the interface is trying to make you implement